# SQL Query. limit an update per rows if condition is X and Y for the same ID number

Tags: sql

Have the following table tblTrans where

```
Trans_ID Trans Sequence Trans_PointsEarned Trans_PointsApplied 
    4452              1                  1                   1 
    4452              2                  1                   1 
    4452              3                  0                   1 
    4462              1                  1                   1 
    4462              2                  1                   1 
    4462              3                  1                   1 
    4462              4                  1                   1 
    4462              5                  1                   1 
    9101              1                  0                   1 
    9101              2                  0                   1 
    9101              3                  0                   1 
    9101              4                  0                   1
```

(useless table doesnt work)

I need to set the following on another field per every customer ID.

So Customer_OverallPoints

```
4452 = 2 (doesn't count 0's)
4462 = 4 (I want to cap the points to 4 based on the sequence and transID and customerID)
9101 = 0 (dont count 0's).
```

This needs to be applied to thousands of records based on customerID and TransID where Trans_Sequence is within the same Trans_ID and it only counts the first 4 rows that have the Trans_pointsEarned = 1.

I tried putting a psuedocode together but it just looked ridicilous and I can't even come up with the logic for this.

Thanks

Comment: Confused. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Are these four tables with one column each?

Comment: Sorry it's just a single table.

Comment: Don't store calculated data, you'll only get data inconsistency. Create a view that returns the current columns plus the calculated value!

Comment: I'm not sure as how the logic would work on Sequence and TransactionID calculation per member based on a constraint of points must be 1 and only 4 rows of 1s will be counted based on their sequence

Comment: @EriadoraOtsito . . . You should tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your question is quite confusing.  You talk about customer ids but the sample data has no such field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `TransId` is really the customer id, I think the basic logic is just an aggregation:

```
select t.TransId,
       (case when sum(t.Trans_PointsEarned) > 4 then 4
             else sum(t.Trans_PointsEarned)
        end) as Customer_OverallPoints
from tblTrans t
group by t.TransId;
```

You can put this into an `update` statement as:

```
update customers c
    set Customer_OverallPoints = (select (case when sum(t.Trans_PointsEarned) > 4 then 4
                                               else sum(t.Trans_PointsEarned)
                                          end)
                                   from tblTrans t
                                   where t.TransId = c.CustomerId
                                  );
```

Comment: Thats perfect. TransId is not the customer Id so requires an inner with another table that has the TransId FK. 
How would we constraint this with another field in tblTrans for dates? 
Table has another field for dates where point is also capped at 4 within that date as well as the sequence?

Comment: @EriadoraOtsito ... You should ask new questions as questions, not in comments.